# Linking a shared library when creating another shared library

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to link a shared library libabc.so present in the folder /home/usr/abc to a shared library libxyz.so. I tried to run the some examples after making the shared library.
The contents of my Makefile are as follows:

```
gcc -L/home/usr/abc/include -Wl,-soname,libxyz.so,-rpath=/home/usr/abc/include -shared -o $@ -labc -lm
```

When I try to run any example using the libxyz.so library, I get undefined reference errors for the libabc.so functions.

EDIT:

I also get the following warning:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libabc.so.1, needed by /home/usr/xyz/src/libxyz.so,not found
(try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Am I using the rpath correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to actually link to your library. You'll need to 
add `-labc` ,  e.g. before the `-lm` flag.

Comment: @Crackej, where is your `libabc.so` library ? And exactly what is the file called ?

Comment: My libabc file is libjemalloc.so. Its stored in the /home/usr/jemalloc/include folder.